# Strange behaviour of fixed toolbar on Android 2.3

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I've noticed a strange behaviour on native Android browser. When toolbar (header) has fixed position the dropdowns inside it don't work at all.

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
<select data-icon="dropdown">
  <option>All</option>
  <option>Recommended</option>
  <option>Favourite</option>
  <option>For me</option>
</select>

<select data-icon="dropdown">
  <option>Name</option>
  <option>Price</option>
  <option>Distance</option>
</select>
```

I'm aware of buggy implementation of this feature on older Androids but are there any fixes or workarounds? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: this is a common issue when using form elements inside `position:fixed` div.

Comment: @Omar so there is no workaround or fix?

Comment: the problem is with scrolling. page/header will scroll once keyboard is visible. you can convert selectmenu into a non-native one by adding `data-native-menu="false"`, try it, it could solve the problem.

Comment: @Omar actually I've tried it but it worked a little unpredictably (at least on android 2.3) - I have two selectmenus and when I click the second one all of them stop working. Weird.